# Tabulator.js accessibility by id does not work

Tags: javascript, tabulator

The accessibility of a Tabulator Table by a global variable works fine, but i can't realy use global Variables, because i'm dynamically generating new Tables.

I just want to access the Tabels by their Container ID.

The code below shows accessability by global variable "table" and by ID, which is provided by the examples (http://tabulator.info/examples/4.3#adddel), but does not work.

See my JSFiddle example of this: https://jsfiddle.net/vs43re6p/41/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    table.addRow({});
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    $("#example-table").tabulator("addRow", {});
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery selection you need to have the Tabulator jQuery wrapper installed:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/install#setup-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
    const table = new Tabulator("#example-table");
    table.addRow({});
});
```

or

```
(function() {
    const table = new Tabulator("#example-table");

    $('#button2').click(function() {
        table.addRow({});
    });
})();
```

Comment: isn't the table still accessed by a global variable? 
The problem is, that i have like: "table1, table2, table3" etc. and they should not receive a global variable. 
The Lib said it provides a way to access the table by id, but it does not work =(

Comment: I don't know if I get it right, but: both examples are wrapped into a function, so the `table` isn't global. Do you have a bit more code for us?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using Tabulator 4.5 or above you can lookup a table by the element ID by using the ***findTable*** function on the `Tabulator` prototype

```
var table = Tabulator.prototype.findTable("#example-table")[0]; // find table object for table with id of example-table
```

The ***findTable*** function will return an array of matching tables. If no match is found it will return `false`

Full details can be found in the [Options Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/options#find-table)